How does the virtual keyword break compilation?
In a class without inheritance, I would expect the virtual keyword to have no noticeable effect. However, in the following code example, adding it breaks compilation. I would like to understand the mechanism behind that.  Why does the virtual keyword break compilation?
It compiles fine without the virtual keyword.
#define USE_VIRTUAL 1
// compile with: cl /W4 /EHsc main.cpp /link /out:main.exe
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

struct Dummy {int i = 3;};
class Uncopyable {
    public:
        // Implicitly delete the copy constructor by having
        // a non-copyable member.
        std::unique_ptr<Dummy> m_innerPtr;

        // A virtual destructor to allow correct inheritance.
        // I first thought that this implicitly deletes the 
        // copy-assignment and copy-constructor, 
        // but it does not. It does, however, implicitly
        // delete the move constructor and assignment.
        virtual ~Uncopyable() = default;

        // accessible constructor
        Uncopyable() = default;
        Uncopyable(std::unique_ptr<Dummy> dummy):m_innerPtr(std::move(dummy)){};

};


template <typename MaybeCopyable>
class Bamboozle {
    public: 
    void foo(std::shared_ptr<MaybeCopyable> obj) {
        std::cout << "Reached Bamboozle::foo(shared_ptr)" << std::endl;
    }

    // overload that takes an object by value
#if USE_VIRTUAL
    virtual
#endif
    void foo(MaybeCopyable obj){
        std::cout << "Reached Bamboozle::foo(Uncopyable)" << std::endl;
        foo(std::make_shared<Uncopyable>(std::move(obj)));
    }
};



int main(int argc, char** argv){
    // construct param objects
    std::shared_ptr<Uncopyable> uncSharedPtr = std::make_shared<Uncopyable>();

    // prints Bamboozle::foo(shared_ptr)
    Bamboozle<Uncopyable> bamboozleObj;
    bamboozleObj.foo(uncSharedPtr);
    return 0;
};


See this question (closed for being too detailed) for more context if you would like to read about other aspects that I think are playing into this. Specifically templates and move constructors. The class template is required to reproduce this behavior.
The Error message is:
cl /W4 /EHsc main.cpp /link /out:main.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33134 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
main.cpp(46): warning C4100: 'argv': unreferenced formal parameter
main.cpp(46): warning C4100: 'argc': unreferenced formal parameter
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(255): error C2280: 'Uncopyable::Uncopyable(const Uncopyable &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
main.cpp(24): note: compiler has generated 'Uncopyable::Uncopyable' here
main.cpp(24): note: 'Uncopyable::Uncopyable(const Uncopyable &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::unique_ptr<Dummy,std::default_delete<Dummy>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<Dummy,std::default_delete<Dummy>> &)'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\memory(3319): note: 'std::unique_ptr<Dummy,std::default_delete<Dummy>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<Dummy,std::default_delete<Dummy>> &)': function was explicitly deleted
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xutility(255): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
main.cpp(51): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Bamboozle<Uncopyable>' being compiled
main.cpp(38): note: while compiling class template member function 'void Bamboozle<Uncopyable>::foo(MaybeCopyable)'
        with
        [
            MaybeCopyable=Uncopyable
        ]
main.cpp(40): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<Uncopyable> std::make_shared<Uncopyable,Uncopyable>(Uncopyable &&)' being compiled
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\memory(2769): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Ref_count_obj2<_Ty>::_Ref_count_obj2<_Ty>(_Ty &&)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=Uncopyable
        ]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\memory(2094): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Construct_in_place<_Ty,_Ty>(_Ty &,_Ty &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=Uncopyable
        ]


fwiw, the other question wasnt closed due to too many details. This one has the same level of details, but is much more focused and specific

You could reduce the diagnostic output to just the relevant error by using int main() instead of the two-argument version.

https://godbolt.org/z/ocbPao87c

Note that if you make your pointers shared rather than unique, your code compiles.

Side note: "In a class without inheritance..." -- when the compiler compiles the code for the class it doesn't (and can't) know that there are no classes derived from this one. virtual says "this function can be overridden", and the compiler has to provide for that possibility.

Adding a destructor silently removes the move constructor and move assignment. It should remove the copy constructor and copy assignment too, but currently doesn't (this is deprecated), so moving such a class silently copies it instead.
Your class doesn't have copy operations to fall back to, so when it loses the move operations, it becomes non-movable.
Add this:
Uncopyable(Uncopyable &&) = default;
Uncopyable &operator=(Uncopyable &&) = default;


As for why adding virtual breaks things. virtual forces the function to be unconditionally instantiated, while non-virtual functions are only instantiated if used, and you can't call the offending function.

Thanks, but why does this behave differently depending on the presence of the virtual keyword?

Because the non virtual foo is not instantiated. Try to call it, and you get the same error. The code is excessively large for a [mcve] and must be a dupe

@3CxEZiVlQ I also call the first foo overload, or do I not?

@HolyBlackCat Thank you. I've tried googling for something like that (virtual forces function to be instantiated) but hadn't found anything saying this so far. Do you happen to know where it is officially mentioned?

adding one line to example to demo explanation: https://godbolt.org/z/zEKK3rhrc

@lucidbrot Here's the part about the move constructor, for example: http://eel.is/c++draft/class#copy.ctor-8.4 Also: https://howardhinnant.github.io/smf.jpg

@HolyBlackCat, do you happen to know where the part about virtual forces [...] can be found/implied?

@Enlico I don't know, but it follows from common sense (all functions in the vtable need to be instantiated, can't do it lazily).

@Enlico it isn't forced, but permitted by [temp.inst#11]

As further explanation I would mention that a compiler is supposed to compile all valid code. It is not required to give an error on bad code (which this is). More so in C++ the SFINAE makes it basically impossible to give an error unless the code is used.

@GoswinvonBrederlow I'm fairly sure it's required to diagnose invalid code, unless the standard says otherwise. That's why we have "ill-formed, no diagnostic required" as a separate concept from just "ill-formed".

@HolyBlackCat s/on bad code/on all bad code/. There is stuff the compiler must catch for sure. A missing constructor or asignment oprator that isn't used isn't one of them. But that goes into language lawyer territory. What I ment was: Just because the compiler gives no error doesn't mean the code isn't invalid. A missing method that isn't called like here is the simplest example of this.

@GoswinvonBrederlow I agree in general, but in this specific case it's legal as long as you don't call the offending template function.

@HolyBlackCat Then it would have to compile with virtual. Instantiating the offending template function, like virtual causes the compiler to do, is enough for the code to fail. Imho the code is invalid. But the compiler is not required to instantiate the offending function unless needed so without virtual you get away with it.

@GoswinvonBrederlow I can't find the relevant wording right now. Closest I've got is http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1, "program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if: no valid specialization ... can be generated for a templated entity", implying that if a valid specialization can be generated (not necessarily with the same arguments of the enclosing class, though this is not mentioned), the code is legal. You can experiment with this, Clang (for example) will try to report errors in templates as early as possible.
